# Ansible - Create complex variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am using Ansible to deploy some virtual machines in ESXi.  I will have variables called iso and floppy_image assigned to each item in inventory.  The variable name is installer in the provided snippet.

I would like to iterate through the inventory and create a variable of "installation media" that needs to be copied to ESXi.  Afterwards I will send the variable to another playbook that will copy the files.

I am currently having issues creating the data structure.  I would like it to look as follows:

`{"esxi1": [file1, ile2], "esxi2": [file1,file2]}`

I've tried using the combine filter which creates the dictionary key but does not append to the array.  My code snippet creates the following data structure but it is not the format I want to use.

`{"esxi1": {"file1": true, "file2": true}, "esxi2": {"file1": true, "file2": true}}`

```
---
- name: create variable for installation media
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        files: {}


- name: playbook to deploy domain controllers
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: domain_controller
  vars:
    base_path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../../../"

  tasks:

    - name: create/set string variable for vsphere
      set_fact:
        vsphere: "{{ item }}"
      when: >
            (ansible_host in hostvars[item]['virtual_machines']) or
            (inventory_hostname in hostvars[item]['virtual_machines'])
      loop: "{{ groups.vsphere }}"
    - debug: var=vsphere

    - debug: var=installer
    - name: set dictionary key of installation media
      set_fact:
        files: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['files'] | combine({ vsphere: { installer: true }}) }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: yes
      when: >
            (installer is defined) and
            (hostvars['localhost']['files'][vsphere] is not defined) or
            (installer not in hostvars['localhost']['files'][vsphere])

- name: results
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - debug: var=files
```